# Why does Entity Framework create a redundant foreign key?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, code-first

I have these 3 classes:

```
public class P
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    public string PId { get; set; }
}

public class E
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("P")]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    public string PId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public string EId { get; set; 
}

public class UF
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("E")]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string PId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("E")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string EId { get; set; }
}
```

When running Entity Framework code-first, I expect to get something like this in the database:

[image]

But what I do get is the above + extra FK to PId:

[image]

i.e. in CREATE SCRIPT we get:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.UF_dbo.E_PId_EId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[UF]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UF] WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UF_dbo.E_PId_EId] 
     FOREIGN KEY([PId], [EId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[E] ([PId], [EId])
          ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

But we also get this extra/redundant FK:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.UF_dbo.P_PId]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[UF]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UF] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UF_dbo.P_PId] 
    FOREIGN KEY([PId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[P] ([PId])
         ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Which results in this error when running the whole CREATE SCRIPT:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.UF_dbo.P_PId' on table 'UF' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 926
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

The question is why?

Comment: Works OK with EF6 after adding navigation properties `E` and `P` (which I hope are not names you're really going to use). Which version is this?

Answer (score 0):

your ids name is incorrect.
rename your id like this:

```
pubilc class P
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class E
{
    public string PId { get; set; }
//Entity Framework automatically recognizes it is a foreign key for P Table.

    public string Id { get; set; }
//don't use EId , For Primary Key just use Id.
}

public class UF
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string PId { get; set; }

    public string EId { get; set; }
//For Foreign key just use: ClassName + Id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not in the question description unfortunately :/

There was an extra virtual memeber P that caused the extra FK:

```
    //Shouldn't be here
    public virtual P P { get; set; }

    public virtual E E { get; set; }
```

Yeah Yeah...